# How to use response probability (logistic model probability) for Sampford Sampling Method in the Sampling package in R?

Tags: r, sampling

I am using the `UPsampford()` function in `Sampling` package in R. I need to select a sample with unequal probability, without replacement and fixed sample size. Sampford’s method is working for probability proportion to size only, (i.e. see case 1 in following example) where sum of inclusion probabilities is equal to n1=5 (sample size) but this method gave some warning message for response probability model where sum of inclusion probabilities is **Not** equal to n1=5 (i.e. see case 2 in following example) and it does not work for my simulated date example where I used n1=200 and gave me warning message like this.

> Error in UPsampford(prob2, eps = 1e-06, max_iter = 500) : Too many iterations. The algorithm was stopped.

In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)

> 1: In .as_int(n) : the argument is not integer

> 2: In .as_int(n - 1) : the argument is not integer

**Question 1:** Can I use response probability in Sampford’ Method?

**Question 2:** Is there any other R package and sampling method (i.e. Madow, midzuno, tille etc) for unequal probability, without replacement and fixed sample where we can use response probability formula (logistic model) instead probability proportion to size formula?

Any solution about case 2?

**Example:**

```
library(sampling)
# auxiliary variable
x <- c(30,45,60,25,80,100,30,67,87,56,23,78, 81, 39, 40)
#case 1
n1=5 #sample size

prob <-inclusionprobabilities(a = x, n = n1)

sum(prob)  #sum(prob) = n1

sample <- UPsampford(prob, eps=1e-6, max_iter=500)
#case 2
xst<-(x-mean(x))/sd(x) #standardized

prob2 <- (exp(xst)/(1+(exp(xst))))

sum(prob2) #sum(prob2) not equal to n1

sample2 <- UPsampford(prob2, eps=1e-6, max_iter=500)
```

Comment: Is it ok if I use prob2 (from case 2) in inclusionprobabilities () i.e.  prob <-inclusionprobabilities(a = prob2, n = n1)?

Comment: For question No. 1, yes we can use response probabilities in inclusionprobabilities () in r, then we can use this inclusion probabilities for unequal probability sampling method.